# Python Name Error during importing function from sibling directiry

Tags: python, nameerror

My project in java and I am using some python scripts for other tasks. My python scripts directory structuring are as follows:

```
Parent Dir 
  - Scripts (driver.py)
  - utils (common.py, helper.py)
```

I want to use functions & classes from `common.py` & `helper.py` in `driver.py` classes. I am importing these in `driver.py` like this:

```
sys.path.append("..")
from utils import *

configs = load_config(filepath)
```

but when I use some functions from `common.py` (lets assume `common.py` imports class `TestClass` from `helper.py` and also has function `load_config(filepath)`) it throws error-

```
NameError: name 'load_config' is not defined
```

Comment: What is the code surrounding the `NameError`?

Comment: `sum` is a builtin. It should always be defined. Or are you using it as example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot import an entire directory like that. You need to import the files individually. You can add a __init__.py file to your utils folder that will be executed when you import the directory the way you are doing. Then you can choose whatever behavior you would like to be carried out in the __init__.py

For instance, your __init__.py could look like this:

```
__all__ = ["common", "helper"]
```

This means that when you call from utils import *, the * will import the modules listed in __all__

Keep in mind you will still need to call common.function_name() if you want to use a function from within common.